# Odoo POS shortcut key

Tags: odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo

Is it possible in odoo POS create some shortcut, For example on keyboard press Esc  call Back button.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this example:

In  **point_of_sale/static/src/js/screens.js**

add

```
$.ctrl = function(key, callback, args) {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(!args) args=[]; // IE barks when args is null 
        if((e.keyCode == key.charCodeAt(0) || e.keyCode == key) && e.ctrlKey) {
            callback.apply(this, args);
            return false;
        }
    });        
};
```

and

```
//DEFAULT ODOO
this.$('.back').click(function(){
    //On button click call
    self.gui.back();
});

//NEW CODE
$.ctrl('27', function() {
    //On CTRL+ESC call
    self.gui.back();
});
```

NOTE:  Maybe is better solution inherit screens.js and add new code!